# .Net Entity Framework - Multiple Tables for the same exact entity

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, ado.net

Objective: Have multiple tables for entities. For example I am creating an HR website where people can have accounts and create personnel entries.

Current model:
Account Table (Name, contact, etc)
Employee Table (Name, contact, dept, etc).

What I want to do is have separate tables for the entity type "employee" in other words each account (client) would have their own employee table.

So currently data looks like

```
Account
acc id   Name
------------------
1        Chevron
2        Texaco

Employee
emp id  acc id  Name 
------------------------
1       1       John
2       1       Stacy
3       2       Cleo
4       2       Johan
```

What I want is

```
Employee table for Chevron
emp id  Name
-----------------------------
1       John
2       Stacy

Employee table for Texaco
emp id   Name
----------------------------
1        Cleo
2        Johan
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you aware of a Database that allows multiple tables with the same name in the same schema?  I sure don't.  So how would you plan on making this work?

Comment: Haven't planned anything out, just curious as I mentioned below. Thanks for reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported by Entity Framework. (And I don't think it should be, since this is bad database design)

Comment: I agree it's bad design. I was more curious than anything. Thanks for your post!